Plotting cophylo with phytools and can't change label.offset
I'm trying to format a cophyloplot using phytools (plot.cophylo) in RStudio (version 2024.09.0+375, with R 4.4.1, on MacOS Sequoia 15.0). The code looks something like this:
cophyloPlaNuc = cophylo(plastomeTree, nuclearTree)
plot(cophyloPlaNuc,
     link.lwd=10, link.lty="solid", link.col="blue", link.type="curved",
     cex=0.8, legend=1, label.offset=0.2)

...which would be straightforward enough, except that as far as I can tell, the label.offset parameter has absolutely no effect. I've tried values over about fifteen orders of magnitude, both positive and negative, and no matter what I always get something like this:

This has some obvious readability and spacing issues, which I cannot for the life of me figure out how to fix. label.offset works fine in plot.tree(); it's only plot.cophylo() that seems to ignore it.
What's going on here? Why does R (or RStudio?) refuse to close that gap or let those trees expand into a readable size?

I don't see any argument called label.offset for the plot.cophylo function. In fact, I get an error if I supply one.

Oh, weird -- I don't get an error, it just doesn't work. If there's no label.offset argument, do you have any idea how I'd fix the graphical problem up there?

Definitely not ideal, but you could add leading and trailing spaces to the tip labels. I don't see a method inherent to the library. I can show you an example of you might add it, just let me know.
